# Repeating function over certain amount of time

Tags: python, mobile

I am writing a program that upload files from my nokia cell phone files to the web server which I am already done writing that. But, my program only does his job only one time and what I want is that I want to call that function for let's say every 5 mins again and again which I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `time` module and the `sleep` function.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop forever and sleep

```
 import time
 while True:
     doUpload()
     time.sleep(300) # sleep in seconds
```

Comment: I tried this method. The point is I have two threads so if I loop forever my phone just go into the loop forever thread and never goes to another thread anymore

Answer (score 0):

Call your function inside a loop:

```
In [1]: import time

In [2]: while True:
   ...:     print 'woke up'
   ...:     time.sleep(2)
   ...:     
   ...:     
woke up
woke up
woke up
woke up
woke up
^C
```

In the above, there is a two-second pause between the 'woke up' messages.

Comment: Is there anyway to do without looping with time.sleep?? any other way . (Threading)